# How to hook into the quick edit action?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
```

This hook only works when submitting a post from post page I want to add action while person select **quick edit** and **update** a post.

Comment: have a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/quick_edit_custom_box

Answer (score 1):

I just erased my previous answer because I realized I was mistaken.  You should be able to hook `save_post` for quick edits.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'Func_Speaker_Save', 10);

function Func_Speaker_Save( $post_id ) {

  if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'custom') {
    // Place code here...
    switch (get_post_status($post_id)) {
      case 'publish':
        // A published post or page
        break;
      case 'pending':
        // post is pending review
        break;
      case 'draft':
        // a post in draft status
        break;
      case 'auto-draft':
        // a newly created post, with no content
        break;
      case 'future':
        // a post to publish in the future
        break;
      case 'private':
        // not visible to users who are not logged in
        break;
      case 'inherit':
        // a revision. see get_children.
        break;
      case 'trash':
        // post is in trashbin
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

More information here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to manage custom post types.  There's a lot more information on the codex I posted as well if you wish.

Comment: add_action('save_post', 'Func_Speaker_Save');
function Func_Speaker_Save($post_id)
{  update_post_meta.....   }

Comment: Sorry - I was mistaken about quick edits using a separate hook.  `save_post` should work.  I have tested the above code in my site, and it works fine.  Note that 'custom' should be replaced with your custom post type.  If the code still isn't working, update your question with the full `Func_Speaker_Save` function.  Perhaps there's a PHP error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this hook is little irrelevant, my purpose is to check my post status while updating post from quick edit i don't want to add more fields in quick edit.

Comment: Right.  My original answer used `quick_edit_custom_box`.  With my updated post, I have now showed how to use `save_post` and how to get the post status using `get_post_status`.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: problem has been resolve when i obtain $_REQUEST['_status'] to get post status in add_action('save_post', 'my_function'); hook  thanks